# Android AsyncTask publishProgress external class

Tags: android, class, android-asynctask

is possible to call the method publishProgress of AsyncTask from a external class?
I've wrote a class for download  a file:

```
    public class ProgressDialogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {
         protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpConnection.downloadFile(mContext,
                            HttpConnection.getFileLength());
         ...
         }
      }
```

it works (the file is downloaded) but I need a progressbar and this progress is into HttpConnection class.
Is possible to call publishProgress method into HttpConnection class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to call publishProgress in doInBackground().

Then you add another method to your ProgressDialogAsyncTask : onProgressUpdate(). This one will be called whenever in your background thread publishProgress() is called...in on ProgressUpdate() you can then call your progress bar... HttpConnection.showProgress() or whatever :)

Example :

```
public class ProgressDialogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {
     protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        int count = 0;
        HttpConnection.downloadFile(mContext,
                        HttpConnection.getFileLength());

        publishProgress(count);
     ...
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Long...update) {
         HttpConnection.showProgress(update[0]);
     }

  }
```

Comment: ok, this is not my case, because I need to call publishProgress in HttpConnection class (for progress download file)

Comment: publishProgress can only be called from inside the AsyncTask, anything else won't make much sense right? Your code is the wrong way around, HttpConnection should be your AsyncTask and there is no reason to have a ProgressDialogAsyncTask ...

Comment: ok, I'll change the way, because HttpConnection is called from different classes